# libcurl error with 32bit computer when using CURLINFO_COOKIELIST

Tags: c#, c++, class, cookies

**Objective**

What I am trying to do is to make a dll from C++(Visual Studio 2012) and call that from C# winform(Visual Studio 2012).

C++ dll is called "Helper.dll".

C# winform is called "WinFormTest.exe".

C++ dll simply connects to a certain web site, and return the html code with cookie string.

Here is my C# code.

```
Form1.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport(@"Helper.dll", EntryPoint="CallTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        private static extern string CallTest(string Url, StringBuilder Cookies);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string path);

        enum PlatformTarget { x64, x86 }
        PlatformTarget _platformTarget;
        string _assPath;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _platformTarget = IntPtr.Size == 8 ? PlatformTarget.x64 : PlatformTarget.x86;
            _assPath        = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            _assPath        = Path.Combine(_assPath, _platformTarget.ToString());
            bool ok         = SetDllDirectory(_assPath);
            if (!ok)
            {
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder _cookies  = new StringBuilder();
            string html             = CallTest("http://www.google.com", _cookies);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no big issue with my C# code.

Here is C++ code.

```
PlusPlusClass.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PlusPlusClass.h"
#include "Scraper.h"

#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR CallTest(const char* Url, char Cookies[])
{
    std::string html;

    try
    {
        CPlusPlusClass* cpc = new CPlusPlusClass();

        std::map<std::string, std::string> cookies;
        html = cpc->GetCookies(Url, cookies);

        std::string cookieData;
        for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator iterator = cookies.begin(); iterator != cookies.end(); iterator++)
        {
            cookieData  += iterator->first;
            cookieData  += "=";
            cookieData  += iterator->second;
            cookieData  += ";";
        }
        sprintf(Cookies, cookieData.c_str(), 0);

        delete cpc;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    return ::SysAllocString(CComBSTR(html.c_str()).Detach());
}

Scraper* class2;

CPlusPlusClass::CPlusPlusClass(void)
{
    class2 = new Scraper();
}

CPlusPlusClass::~CPlusPlusClass(void)
{
    delete class2;  --> here, I get the error. The error just kills my C# application.
}

std::string CPlusPlusClass::GetCookies(const char* Url, std::map<std::string, std::string>& Cookies)
{
    return class2->DoSomething(Url, Cookies);
}
```

Here is Scraper.cpp.

```
Scraper.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Scraper.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

// split
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

Scraper::Scraper(void)
{
}


Scraper::~Scraper(void)
{
}

std::string Scraper::DoSomething(const char* Url, std::map<std::string, std::string>& Cookies)
{
    std::string _retValue;
    curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );

    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_slist* headerlist   = NULL;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Accept: */*");
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, Url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &_retValue);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        // receive cookies
        struct curl_slist* cookies  = NULL;
        struct curl_slist* nc;
        CURLcode ret = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);
        nc = cookies;
        while (nc)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
            boost::split(split_vector, nc->data, boost::is_any_of("\t"));

            Cookies.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::string>(split_vector[5], split_vector[6]) ); --> here is the problem, I think.

            nc = nc->next;
        }

        // clean up
        curl_slist_free_all(cookies);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return _retValue;
}

std::string Scraper::DoSomething2(const char* Url, std::map<std::string, std::string>& Cookies)
{
    std::string temp = "some    value   is  not good    enough";
    std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
    boost::split(split_vector, temp, boost::is_any_of("\t"));

    Cookies.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::string>(split_vector[0], split_vector[1]) );
    return "this function is okay";
}
```

It's just simple curl example to connect to a certain web site.

But from C#, I have to retrieve cookies as well as html, so I am passing StringBuilder to C++.

So, C++ can write cookie name and value to that StringBuilder.

Actually this codes work great in 64bit.

[image]

But if I change it into 32bit(in C# winform property), C++ gives me error in CPlusPlusClass::~CPlusPlusClass(void).

When I try to delete class2 which is Scraper class, it just kills my C# application, so I cannot even trace the error.

I am specious about Scraper.cpp when getting the cookie from curl CURLINFO_COOKIELIST.

And write them to char array which was referenced from C# StringBuilder.

So, I wrote down DoSomething2 function in Scraper.cpp.

Now, it works even when I am deleting class in 32bit or 64bit.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By somehow it was fixed.

I don't know very much about the mechanism x86 nor x64, but it seems that the basic capacity are different.

I edited to fix the size of StringBuilder when I first start from C#.

```
StringBuilder _cookies  = new StringBuilder();
to
StringBuilder _cookies  = new StringBuilder(1024);
```

And now, I don't see that error again in 32bit computers.

Happy coding!!